# AJAX not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've spent a day checking this code, but still can't find where the error is.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <br/>
  <label for="name">Class ID</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="csid" name="csid">
    <option>----------Please select a Class Code---------</option>
    <?php
      $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM class WHERE class_status='Active' ");
      $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
      if($rowCount > 0) {
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row['class_id'].'">'.$row['class_code'].'</option>';
        }
      }
      else {
        echo '<option value="">Class ID not available</option>';
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <br/>
  <label for="name">Subject Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subid" id="subid" disabled/>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#csid').change(function(){
         var classid = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'ajax.php',
           data:{classid:classid},
           success:function(data){
             $('#subid').val(data);
           }
         });
       });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my `ajax.php` file:

```
<?php

include('dataconnect.php');

if (isset($_POST['classid'])) 
{
    $qry = "select * from class where class_id=". $_POST['classid'];
    $rec = mysql_query($qry);
    if (mysql_num_rows($rec) > 0) {
        while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($rec)) {
            echo $res['class_status'];
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Can anyone let me know where the error is, as I really can't find it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the issue you are having.

Comment: Have you tried [**debugging**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) your code?

Comment: Also, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Yeah, I can't find any error in my code, in console also got no error, it just don't work when I onchange my #csid. And I had also try other's code to check whether my ajax is working or not, and it is working.

Comment: console.log(data); what's in it ?

Comment: @deg Hi, I had try and it is the data that I want from database.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you, I had switching the to MySQLi and it is working now!

Comment: @Beginner -- No problem, glad the issue got resolved. I'll write that as an answer so you can resolve this question :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge YEah, Sure! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP 7, your code won't have any output due to the fact that the `mysql_` constructor is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql) (and [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)).

Switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) will fix this problem.

In addition to this, please ensure that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). :)